# How can I zip a collection of XMLDocuments and save it to a directory in C#

Tags: c#, xml, zip

I am signing documents with `digital signature` and adding them to a `collection` of `XmlDocs`.

I do not want to save them anywhere, simply zip them if there is more than 1 `XML doc` or save the `XML` to a folder.

Now I looked into `ZipFile` that comes from `System.Io.Compression` but it takes only strings that are the source and destination.

For a bit of clarification here is my code:

```
var xmlDocsSigned = new List<XmlDocument>();

foreach (var document in documents)
{                
   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
// logic that Generate XML from object and load it to that XML.
// logic that signs the XML
}

xmlDocsSigned.Add(doc);
```

So far I have done it with saving the `XML files` and zipping the folder, but 
I do not want them to be saved anywhere as I only need the `zip`. If it is only one `XML` then of course it will be saved.

Do you know any open source libraries that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.8) class? That seems to fit your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some libraries for that.
One of the most using for zip is DotNetZip
[DotNetZip Library](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dotnetzip)

Just look at the website to find out what you can do with XML files!.

And there are many examples for zipping!, Find out here [DotNetZip - C# Examples](http://grapevine.dyndns-ip.com/download/authentec/download/dotnetzip/examples.htm)

Comment: Thank you Esmaeli. I have used DonetZip and a memory stream and now I can do my task. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

[ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive) might be the droid you are looking for. It let's you handle ZipFiles like folder/like Windows does since Vista.

Fun fact: The current Office Formats are little more then XML files in a renamed ZIP container. It is actually possible to process them with this class and the XML ones. Of course the proper SDK is still better, but I do like to point to his fact in favor of the new Formats.